# Joining another entity by foreign key

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Just recently got into using Doctrine and after getting somewhat comfortable with the basics I'm now trying to implement one of the more complex structures I have at my hand being the user. Every user has a designated class which is saved in a different table all of its own.

After reading up on the Doctrine documentation and different help topics online I've come up with the current state of things.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

require_once 'UserClass.php';

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */

    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="userclass", inversedBy="id")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userclass_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @ORM\Column(name="userclass", type="integer")
     */
    private $userClass;


    public function getByID($id)
    {
        if (empty($id))
        {
            return null;
        }

        $q = $this->queryBuilder->select("u")
                                ->from(User::class, "u")
                                ->where("u.id = $id")
                                ->getQuery();

        return $q->getResult();
    }
```

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="userclass")
 */
class UserClass
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;
```

Running `user->getByID()` now correctly returns a user object if it ends up finding any but the `userClass` property is still only the foreign key saved in the database when I, from what I understood, expected it to be the entry from the `UserClass` table with the appropriate ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="userclass", inversedBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userclass_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\Column(name="userclass", type="integer") <-- delete this
 */
private $userClass;
```

You must not combine `@ORM\ManyToOne` with `@ORM\Column`. ORM will infer foreign key's type on its own.